# file_put_contents permission denied -- any solution without 777?

Tags: php, file-permissions, user-permissions

I'm working on a page where a user can upload an image/video using a form. The code includes this line:

> move_uploaded_file($tempfile, $newfile)

Then a thumbnail is automatically created from this image/video and uploaded to the server like this:

> file_put_contents($thumbname, $thumbnail)

Now the uploading of the image works perfectly but the thumbnail can't be saved and I get this response:

> Warning: file_put_contents(thumbnails/1.jpg): failed to
>   open stream: Permission denied in
>   SITEURL/upload.php on line 17

My two questions:

1. Why does the user have permission uploading an image via `move_uplaoded_file` but uploading the thumbnail via `file_put_contents` gets denied? Please note that both files, image AND thumbnail, get uploaded to the same folder. Shouldn't the user have either permission to do both or neither?
2. I do realize there is already a thread like this but the suggested answer there is to run `chmod 777`. But I read that setting a folder to 777 is *always* a security risk. Is there a way to fix this problem without 777?
   Again, I don't understand why I have to change the permission to 777 for `file_put_contents` whereas `move_uploaded_file` works just fine at 755.

Comment: `chmod -R u+rwx,g-rw,o-x thumbnails/` gives read, write, and execute rights to the owner, but denies execute access for group and others. `chmod` is powerful enough to [manage rights more carefully](http://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/permissions.html). More carefully than 777, that's for sure

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Isn't that just longhand for `chmod -R 766`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Yes, it is, but I find the `u+rwx` and `g-wx` notation a lot clearer: _U_ser, _G_roup, _O_ther, _A_ll, `+` for grant, `-` for deny and _R_ead, _W_rite, e_X_ecute... (of course, you know this, but this explanation is directed at the OP ;-P)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Fair enough - maybe I'm just more of a "numbers" person because I find `766` much easier to understand XD

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: To each his own, as long as we all agree that `chmod  -R 777` is best avoided, it's all good

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Agreed. `chmod -R 777` is about as "problem-solving" as `eval`...

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
// PHP code:
echo `whoami`;
```

to find out what user PHP is being run as.

Then check on your server who owns `thumbnails`

```
# log in via SSH and run:
ls -l | grep thumbnails
```

This should show you a line like this (taken from my own server):

```
drwxr-xr-x 8 niet niet 4096 Jul 15 12:12 thumbnails
```

In the above example, the folder is owned by the user `niet` and is in the group `niet`. If it is not the same as `whoami` from ealier, you will need to change the *owner* of the folder. For instance if `whoami` gave `user3041398`, you would do:

```
chown user3041398 thumbnails
```

Run the `ls` line again and you should see your username in the output now, and PHP should be able to write to the folder.

Comment: The php code gave me 'www-data', so i changed the user of thumbnails from root to 'www-data'. and it worked! thank you so much!!

Comment: @user3041398 Glad I could help :) Please consider Accepting this answer ^_^